# Persistent background checking with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

First time poster, long time lurker. I've gotten a lot of great advice to problems from this site, but I haven't found anything here for the topic of this question. Normally I would bug our SME at the office but he's indisposed.

So, we use Selenium Web Driver to do automated tests. I'm working on an application with some mapping and demographics features, so my tests are very function vs. form oriented.

My tests are written such that I have classes/methods that are a part of the puzzle (the site is essentially one workflow where you go from page 1 to page 5 and the same actions need to be performed in steps 2-3, for example, but test A might do something different on page 4 to see the result in page 5. Clear as mud?

Anyways, during manual tests, I can sometimes see an error message pop up on the site (a hidden div that will become visible if it detects an error, but it's usually a very generic/vague error). This error sometimes pops up even if you're able to go through the flow with no other ill-effects. However, I want to capture when these errors happen so I can look for patterns - if this means just logging it to console or failing the test...I can figure that out later.

The immediate problem is having a persistent check in place that will always look for this error during every test. I could create a method and call it in my "action" methods, though this would leave gaps and slow the tests down. Is there any clever way of implementing something like this without slowing the tests down or calling this check every time I do a step in the process? Also, forgive me, I'm still learning Java and the selenium web driver, so if I've said anything stupid, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Since this message is persistent if it is there, you might try adding a check for it in your test case teardown method.  (I would recommend that you reduce the implicit wait time before you do that check, though, otherwise each test will take an extra amount of time waiting for an error message that isn't there.)

Another possible option is to define your own listener on your own test runner and update the testFinished() method to go check for your error message.  [See this](http://www.swtestacademy.com/junit-listeners/) for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks - I'm researching the possibility of creating a custom runner. However, to be clear, the error itself does not remain visible through the test - it will appear for about 3 seconds and then goes back into a hidden state.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like the error messages are always in known locations on each page, I would create a method (or methods, depending on how many error message locations there are on a given page) that looks to see if an error exists and then log it before leaving the page. It sounds like you might be using the page object model. If so, you can add these methods to the each relevant page object for easy access.

NOTE: Checking for errors once before you leave the page may not be enough. You may need to check each time you do some action that might cause an error. This is probably not a bad practice anyway because it will help in debugging errors because you will notice an error closer to the time it was triggered, thus narrowing down what caused the error.

If you have the ability, do something like log it as a warning so that it doesn't fail your test but stands out (and is searchable) in your logs.

You seem concerned that checking for all these errors will significantly slow your script. If properly written, it shouldn't add a significant delay. One significant delay you might run into is if you have implicit waits turned on and are checking for elements that don't exist (e.g., unless there's an error). This will cause the implicit wait to be applied each time you search for the missing element and will likely add significant time to the run time. My suggestion is to turn off implicit waits and add explicit waits only where needed. Searching for any element will add some time but 25ms here and there should be negligible in an overall script run.

Comment: You are correct. I've gone ahead and added a very simple check to the action that yields the error the most. Previously, I would use a method in our framework that would wait until a page object becomes visible before proceeding to the next step. Instead, I created a method that will check for the error and fail the test (might change later) if it shows up during the analysis process. It polls every 500ms and will stop as soon as the analysis is complete, so there's no impact to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using EventFiringWebDriver?

There is an answer here on what it does:
[What is EventFiringWebDriver in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092480/what-is-eventfiringwebdriver-in-selenium)

Newer selenium versions have more types of events present in the interface, which can broaden its use on these types of tests.

Comment: Hey.. do consider summarizing the important points raised in the link so your answer is more helpful.. it will also be a great help in case the page goes 404 in the future!