# What is EventFiringWebDriver in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new user on stackoverflow and also new in selenium, so please guide me about What is the EventFiringWebDriver in selenium and what the use of it.

Comment: google knows. Ask him...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EventFiringWebDriver` is a `JavaClass`, basically it is a wrapper around an arbitrary `WebDriver` instance which supports registering of `WebDriverEventListener`.

For more details refer [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

**EventFiringWebDriver** is a method in selenium use to wrap the **webdriver** and **WebEventListner** is also method to get the message from **eventfiringwebdriver** instance (like e_driver). need to register the instance of **WebEventListner** with the instance of **EventFiringWebDriver** to get the **driver**

Comment: An example would improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Initializing instance of Firefox WebDriver
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);

// Initializing EventFiringWebDriver using Firefox WebDriver instance
    e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);


//create object of EventListerHandler to registeritwithEventFiringWebDriver
        eventListener = new WebEventListener();

        e_driver.register(eventListener);

        e_driver.manage().window().maximize();
        e_driver.get(appURL);
```

Refer this. hope u can understand.